# Problems Scanner in Java

Tags: java

I was having difficculties when trying to read from a JOPtionPane input dialog using a Scanner object (text below)

```
int array[] = new int[6];
for (int i=0; i<6; i++)
    { 
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a number to fill the array: ");
        array[i]=sc.nextInt(System.in);
    }
```

Difficulties got solved when changed code like follows:

```
String st;
int array[] = new int[6];
for (int i=0; i<6; i++)
    { 
        st= JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a number to fill the array: ");
        array[i] = Integer.parseInt(st);
    }
```

I would like to know why I can't fill the array using a Scanner class object :/

Comment: `JOPtionPane` and `Scanner` get their input from two completely different sources.

Comment: Reading from `System.in` means you will read the input in the console, not from the `JOptionPane`, that why the first option didn't worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scanners can be set to take input from multiple different places, but unfortunately not from JOptionPane. If you want to use Scanner, you'll have to pick a different method of input. Either a file, existing string or Console input.

[Java 6 API - class Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#Scanner%28java.io.File%29)

JOptionPane collects its input from only one place, itself.

[Java 6 API - class JOptionPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html)